# Python Как избавиться от \\

Tags: python

Экранирую звездочки в csv с помощью python 2.7.
При выполнении кода

```
row = ["asda", "asda*", "* asd"]
row = [element.replace('*', '\*') if '*' in element else element for element in row]
row: ["asda", "asda\\*", "\\* asd"]
```

В итоге csv.writer записывает в csv двойной бекслеш.

```
writer = csv.writer(fb, delimiter="|", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='\\')
writer.writerow(row)
```

Все перепробовал, уже ничего в голову не приходит...

Comment: Зачем вы экранируете звездочки?

Comment: Кавычек в первой строке не хватает, код поехал

Comment: @insolor, после отработки кода я получаю 2 csv файла. В первом лежат заголовки, во втором данные. Из этих csv формируются таблицы в представлении markdown. Без экранирования звездочек -- звездочки превращают таблицы в маркированные списки. А так как после отработки кода получаются 2 бекслеша -- крон выражения в таблицах (и другие данные) становятся не совсем верными. Парсер markdown один бекслеш  скрывает (экранируя появление списков, применение курсива, выделение текста), а второй бекслеш уже делает данные в таблице некорректными.

Comment: ну так вы решаете совсем не ту проблему и задаете совсем не тот вопрос. Вам нужно решать проблему, чтобы звездочки не создавали маркированный список, а не избавляться от //. Двойной // записывается как раз, потому что один / это / и есть, а второй - символ экранирования. И парсер ваш экранирует не "появление списков", а как раз этот самый бэкслэш, который вы добавляете.

Comment: @FykosPokys если markdown, то как вариант можно не экранировать, а все содержимое ячейки в \`\` оборачивать, будет выделено как код, типа `asda*`. Еще мне кажется лучше вообще не использовать модуль csv в данном случае, а просто вручную генерировать markdown таблицу.

Comment: @Эникейщик, как раз таки двойной бекслеш появляется после выполнение py кода. Есть ли возможность отключить экранирование бекслеша в ```row = [element.replace('*', '\*') if '*' in element else element for element in row]``` ?

Comment: @insolor, избавиться от csv в данном случае сложно( Изначально данные для таблицы экспортирую из psql в формате csv. Далее с помощью кода на python я форматирую эти данные для того чтобы парсер Markdown смог построить таблицу.

Comment: @FykosPokys, тогда просто оборачивайте код в ячейках в косые апострофы вместо экранирования

Comment: Ну и вы экспортируете в csv, но дальше скрипт уже не обязан результат опять в csv выводить, можно сразу скриптом markdown таблицы генерировать.

Comment: ну правильно, вы добавляли бэкслэш как символ и питон экранировал его, чтобы он и оставался как символ

Answer (score 1):

Сам себе создал проблему и замучил вас.

Я пытался избежать дополнительное оборачивание в двойные кавычки с помощью `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE`. Для того чтобы код в ошибку не падал добавил параметр `escapechar='\\'`.

Именно параметр `escapechar='\\'` послужил дополнительным экранирование бекслеша.

Спасибо всем за помощь!